# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.event.enrichment.BeforeEnrichment: method <init>()V not found

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I am trying to test my ReST service with arquillian and wildfly 10.0 and I am getting the above error.

There must be a problem with versions of the various libraries I am using but I can't figure out which one. My dependencies are (snippet from my ivy.xml file):

```
<dependency org="org.jboss.arquillian" name="arquillian-bom" rev="1.1.11.Final" conf="test->default"/>
<dependency org="org.jboss.arquillian.junit" name="arquillian-junit-container" rev="1.1.2.Final" conf="test->default"/>
<dependency org="org.wildfly.arquillian" name="wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded" rev="2.0.0.Final" conf="test->default"/>
<dependency org="org.wildfly.security" name="wildfly-security-manager" rev="1.1.2.Final" conf="test->default"/>
<dependency org="org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver" name="shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain" rev="2.2.4" conf="test->default"/>
<dependency org="org.jboss.arquillian.extension" name="arquillian-rest-client-impl-3x" rev="1.0.0.Final-SNAPSHOT" conf="test->default"/>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

So the arquillian-junit-container revision has to be the same as that of arquillian-bom (in this case 1.1.11.Final)